# Best way to get an xml representation of an object with c#?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, serialization

What is the easiest way to get an XML representation of an object in c#?
I know you can use XmlSerializer  but I wonder if there's a better way.

Can I somehow use LINQ for this?

Update: By best I mean I can use it with immutable objects and I don't need to make a constructor with no prarameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this example helps - covers both XML serialization and deserialization using LINQ:

http://thecodeslinger.wordpress.com/2007/12/17/custom-xml-serialization-with-linq/

Also there's LINQ to XSD (it's in incubation, not sure if that matters to you - it doesn't to me...):

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/LINQToEverythingLINQToXSDAddsMoreLINQiness.aspx

Scott Hanselman makes this comment:

> LINQ to XSD creates .NET classes with
>   much better fidelity than what's
>   created with (the aging) XSD.exe.

Download link here:

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=a45f58cd-fcfc-439e-b735-8182775560af&displaylang=en

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what you mean by "better". Personally I like to use LINQ to XML for custom serialization of objects. It gives you full control over serialization (allowing you to easily change the schema over time, potentially retaining elements or attributes that the current code version doesn't understand) while still being compact in code.

I've used this in a few places now, and been pleased with the results. It would be a pain for very large and complicated types, certainly - but for reasonably simple data structures it's great.

I'm personally not terribly fond of relying on things like XmlSerializer and BinarySerializer. They tend to give you *just not quite enough* control to do everything you want, or add extra requirements like parameterless constructors.

Comment: Could you give me an example? I am having trouble with using XmlSerializer  because it requires read/write public fields.  But I want to have an immutable structure.

Comment: @wcf guru needed: In that case you'd probably write either a constructor taking an XElement or a static method called FromXElement which created an instance appropriately. You'd also create an instance method of `ToXElement` which performed the serialization. Immutability is definitely one of the benefits of a hand-rolled approach.

Comment: I can only find reference to creating objects from xml using LINQ but not the other way around creating XML from an object.  Could you point me to a reference or a function name to start with?  Would appreciate it.

Comment: @wcf guru: Any LINQ to XML tutorial should show you how to build elements. Generally it's just a matter of calling appropriate constructors :) I would try to play with LINQ to XML *in general* before starting to think about how to use it for serialization.

Comment: Ya I guess I was hoping for an automatic serializer that I didn't need to build the XElements myself.  Everywhere I look you have to build it yourself and then I guess I'll have to expose a method to work with collections too for serializing.

Comment: @Jon - Given the additional immutable object requirement, yours is indeed the correct answer.